# Manual double-sided printing on iOS

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, printing

I have an AirPrint printer with no Duplex functionality. When I want to print double sided documents from mac, I can easily print odd pages first, then manually reinsert the papers and print only the even pages. Is there a way or even an app to do the same thing on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't printing very long documents, one option would be to manually deselect the even/odd pages in the Print dialog.

[image: deselect pages]

Comment: Unluckily, the documents are 50+ pages

Comment: I looked into a number of popular PDF apps, and unfortunately none of them seem to offer this feature.

Comment: I use an app PDF Printer to print 2-sided but it will depend on your printer. When I open the app and the document I want to print the window has me select my printer. When I do that I get an option for 2-sided printing. Don't know it this will work for you.

Comment: The screen I get looks like the one you included in your post.  When I select my printer an option appears for 2 sided printing. I state again it depends on printer as you probably know already.

Comment: @jmh The premise of the question at hand is that the printer *doesn't* support duplex printing, and Fayez needs a way to do it manually.

Comment: yes i just figuered that out! lol.. I missed the word manual.  Sorry to waste your time.